# Upgrade mongodb 3.2 to 3.4 on debian 8

Tags: mongodb, debian

From the docs:

> If you installed MongoDB from the MongoDB apt, yum, dnf, or zypper repositories, you should upgrade to 3.4 using your package manager.

So I followed [these steps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) for Debian.

I restarted mongo.

I still have version 3.2.9.

What should I do to get 3.4 activated?

apt list gives this:

```
mongodb-org/jessie,now 3.4.3 amd64 [installed]
mongodb-org-mongos/wheezy,now 3.2.9 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.3]
mongodb-org-server/wheezy,now 3.2.9 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.3]
mongodb-org-shell/wheezy,now 3.2.9 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.3]
mongodb-org-tools/wheezy,now 3.2.9 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.3]
```

Comment: Have you *installed MongoDB from the MongoDB apt, yum, dnf, or zypper repositories* ? What is the output from step 4 "apt-get install"?

Comment: @AlexBlex from apt. I didnt save the output from apt-get install. Are there any logs? I did not see any errors.

Comment: You had to uninstall one from Debian 7 repo. Now you have both installed. I'd recommend to uninstall both, then instal the new one. Don't forget to backup first, configs in particular.

Comment: @AlexBlex. A simple apt-get upgrade did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For others, if apt-get upgrade did not work. Make sure you followed the instructions from [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) before.

The problem might be that you only look for update or upgrade from 3.2 repo. Check under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to see if there's any 3.4.

After adding the key as per the doc and adding 3.4 repo, just do `apt upgrade`.

Restart mongod.